# How to display list items according by text field search?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a list with results that need to be hidden by default and hidden again when search field is blank/backspaced. If no results found, show message or result indicated "no matching found". I had a previous post with similar question but had to abandon that since it was made using bootstrap which conflicts with my Wordpress theme setup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myUL li").hide();
  $('#contact').hide();
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you state the question more succinctly

Comment: Updated and simplified my question. Listed point form of things I am looking for.

Comment: You still might want to rephrase and focus your post, the answer right now is "yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses a slightly refactored version of your code, including:

- a 'keyup' event listener (instead of an inline event handler)
- a new CSS selector called `.hidden`
- a new HTML element called `no-results`
- two helper functions for dealing with list items

The event listener and the CSS selector help with **separation of concerns** on the page. (Styling is done by CSS rather than manually by JavaScript, and events are handled by JavaScript alone rather than being included in the page's markup.) The `no-results` element and the helper functions are just **personal preference**, but I think they keep things neater.

**See the in-code comments** for further explanation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const

    // Identifies DOM elements
    input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
    noResults = document.getElementById("no-results"),
    listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#myUL li")),

    // Defines a function to get uppercased li text
    getLiUpperText = (li) => {
      const
        a = li.getElementsByTagName("a")[0],
        text = a.textContent || a.innerText
      liUpperText = text.toUpperCase();
      return liUpperText;
    },

    // Defines a function to hide all list items
    hideListItems = () =>
      listItems.forEach((li) => li.classList.add("hidden"));


  // Hides everything initially (using CSS instead of manual styling)
  noResults.classList.add("hidden");
  hideListItems();

  // Calls inputListener on keyup
  input.addEventListener("keyup", inputListener);


  // Defines inputListener
  function inputListener(event) {

    hideListItems(); // Tentatively hides all names
    const inputUpperText = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    if (inputUpperText === "") {
      return; // Quits early if input is empty
    }
    noResults.classList.remove("hidden"); // Tentatively shows 'no results'

    for (let li of listItems) {
      if (getLiUpperText(li).includes(inputUpperText)) {
        li.classList.remove("hidden"); // Shows item
        noResults.classList.add("hidden"); // Hides 'no results'
      }
    }
  }

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hidden {
  /* new ruleset for hiding elements */
  display: none;
}

#myInput {
  /* background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); */
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<div>
  <p id="no-results">No match found</p>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this in my Wordpress page but the results don't seem to be hidden.

Comment: Does the snippet above work properly for you? (I've only tested this in the latest Chrome browser, so it's possible that your browser behaves differently.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to check if input value is present to hide/show the UL.
Call this function on input change and page onload

```js
checkInputValueAndHideList()

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    
    checkInputValueAndHideList()
    
}

function checkInputValueAndHideList() {
    const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    const noResult = document.getElementById("no-result");

//        console.log('input.value', input.value) 
    
    if(!input.value) {
        ul.style.display = 'none'
        noResult.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        ul.style.display = 'block'
        noResult.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<h2>My Phonebook</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="no-result">
No match found
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try typing "RR" inside the input (which does not exist!), it should show "No match found"